# Unable while using Rvest and Selenium to extract text specific text located in <span> object from LinkedIn

Tags: r, web-scraping

First of all, I'm only a beginner in R so my apologies if this sound like a dumb question.

Basically, I want to scape the experience section in LinkedIn and extract the name of the position. As an example, I picked the profile of Hadley Wickham. As you can see on this [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/io7Ke.png), the data I need ("Chief Scientist") is located in a Span object, with the span object itself located within several Div objects.

As a first attempt, I figured that I'll just try to extract directly the text from the Span objects using this code. However and unsurprisingly, it returned every text that was in other Span objects.

```
    role <-signals %>%
  html_nodes("span") %>%
  html_nodes(".visually-hidden") %>%
  html_text()
```

I can isolate the text I need by subsetting "[ ]" the object but I'm gonna apply this code to several LinkedIn profiles and the order of the title will change depending on the page. So I thought "Ok maybe I need to specify to R that I want to target the Span object that is located in the experience section and not the whole page" so I thought that I'll just need to mention in the code the "#experience" so that it only pick the Span object I need. But it only returned an empty object.

```
    role <-signals %>%
  html_nodes("#experience") %>%
  html_nodes("span") %>%
  html_nodes(".visually-hidden") %>%
  html_text()
```

I'm pretty sure I'm missing some steps here but I can't figure out what. Maybe I need to specify each objects that are between "#experience" and "span" in order for this code to work but I feel there must be a better and easier way. Hope this make sense. I spent a lot of time trying to debug this and I'm not skilled enough in scraping to find a solution on my own.

Comment: This task needs `RSelenium`

Comment: I'm a complete beginner in Scraping and don't really understand how RSelenium works. Can you provide some code for this particular case or help me understand what I need to do to make this works ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is, this requires `RSelenium` since data is rendered after the page loads and not with reading pre-defined html page. Refer here on how to launch a browser (either Chrome, Firefox, IE etc..) with the object as `remdr`

The below snippet opens Firefox but there are other ways to launch any other browser

```
selCommand <- wdman::selenium(jvmargs = c("-Dwebdriver.chrome.verboseLogging=true"), retcommand = TRUE)
shell(selCommand, wait = FALSE, minimized = TRUE)
remdr <- remoteDriver(port = 4567L, browserName = "firefox")
Sys.sleep(format(runif(1,10,15),digits = 1))
remdr$open()
```

You might have to login to LinkedIn since it won't allow viewing profiles without signing up. You will need to use the `RSelenium` `clickElement` and `sendKeys` functions to operate the webpage.

```
remdr$navigate(url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/') # navigate to the link
username <- remdr$findElement(using = 'id', value = 'session_key') # finding the username field
username$sendKeysToElement(list('your_USERNAME'))
password <- remdr$findElement(using = 'id', value = 'session_password') # finding the password field
password$sendKeysToElement(list('your_PASSWORD'))
remdr$findElement(using = 'xpath', value = "//button[@class='sign-in-form__submit-button']")$clickElement() # find and click Signin button
```

Once the page is loaded, you can get the page source and use `rvest` functions to read between the HTML tags. You can use this [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ruto-xpath-finder/ilcoelkkcokgeeijnopjnolmmighnppp) to easily get `xpath` selectors for the text you want to scrape.

```
pgSrc <- remdr$getPageSource()
pgData <- read_html(pgSrc[[1]])
experience <- pgData %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = "//div[@class='text-body-medium break-words']") %>%
  html_text(trim = TRUE)
```

Output of experience:

```
> experience
[1] "Chief Scientist at RStudio, Inc."
```